# difficult query: Join Parameter, self join, and contradicting conditions

Tags: mysql, dql, self-join

I have a Database with a table named translations.(amazing...)

In this table are 4 rows: **id**, **textidea**, **translation** and **language**.

**id** is a regular id as every primary key

**textidea** is the id of the idea behind the word, like an image: when i mean 'tree' the idea can be translated in other languages

**translation** is the translation of the textidea

and **language** is the language in of the translation

The short function to this table is: textidea + language = translation

Not every textidea has a translation in every Language: I have 10 Languages and 1100 Textideas, but only 7000 Translations

My job is to fetch every single textidea and the english translation where the target language does not yet have a translation from the database

ill pack it in a txt file and can massively translate the words from english to other languages

my sql query ist quite working: it gets no result(empty result):

```
SELECT t.textidea,t.translation 

FROM translation AS t  
LEFT JOIN translation AS w             //table joins itself

ON t.textidea = w.textidea 
WHERE (t.language = 'en-US' 
   AND w.language = 'de-DE'             //de-DE is German and is as example 
   AND w.translation IS NULL            //target language here
   AND t.translation IS NOT NULL)
```

what can i do in my sql query better?
if possible you can do a dql query, because im using doctrine too

Thanks

EDIT:
if i'm doing a left join, with less entrys than the main table:

```
---------------------
|entry 1|added entry|
---------------------
|entry 2|null       |
---------------------
```

i have an entry with null: I want to search that entry

Problem:
i want it a special language ~ where de.language = 'de-DE'

but this excludes null

-> can i join with a parameter? so i can put "where de.language ='de-DE'" there and search later for null?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found out:

after '**JOIN**' follows '**ON**' and in this we can specify the join condition, but also things we would put in '**WHERE**'

this makes it possible to have tailored tables, which can be tailored on in where

sooo :

old query:

```
SELECT t.textidea,t.translation 

FROM translation AS t  
LEFT JOIN translation AS w             

ON t.textidea = w.textidea 
WHERE (t.language = 'en-US' 
   AND w.language = 'de-DE'         
   AND w.translation IS NULL            
   AND t.translation IS NOT NULL)
```

change:

```
ON t.textidea = w.textidea AND w.language = 'de-DE'
```

new working query:

```
SELECT t.textidea,t.translation 

FROM translation AS t  
LEFT JOIN translation AS w             

ON t.textidea = w.textidea AND w.language = 'de-DE'
WHERE (t.language = 'en-US' 
   AND w.translation IS NULL            
   AND t.translation IS NOT NULL)
```